# Replace "\n" depending on how the line started

Tags: sed

**I am trying to replace line endings ('\n') with multiple characters ("<br>\n") (so no using tr) in a file, but only for certain lines, depending on how they start.**

### What I want :

Document in :

```
# Title

paragraph,
with text over multiple lines

- list item
- other list item
 - sublist item
 - sublist item 2
```

Output :

```
# Title

paragraph,<br>
with text over multiple lines<br>

- list item
- other list item
 - sublist item
 - sublist item 2
```

You probably guessed it, I am trying to force line break on single newlines (in paragraphs) when I later convert my markdown document to html.

### What I tried/know

**I have looked up the syntax of regexes and basics of the 'sed' command, so my understanding is that I need something that'd use a negative lookback to not match a particular beginning, then maybe a non-capturing group or positive lookback for the content of the line then the actual match on \n and the thing I want to replace with.**

If you consider an example where I'd only exclude line starting with (1 or more '#' followed by a space) or ([maybe space] then [a dash] then [one space]), what I'm currently using is :

```
#DOESN'T WORK (and ~/Documents/test/foo contains exactly the example I put above)
sed -z 's/(?<!#+\s|\s*-\s)(?:[^\n]*)\n/<br>\n/g' ~/Documents/test/foo
```

#### What I understand of my command

Maybe my understanding of sed/regexes in a bash context is wrong so I'll explain how I understand what I wrote :

```
sed -z     # -z flag to treat the document as one big string, apparently good when
           # dealing with newlines replacement (https://linuxhint.com/newline_replace_sed/)
           # string with the command
'          #'
s/         # s(ubstitute) command in sed
(?<!#+\s|\s*-\s) # negative lookback ignoring '#+\s' (one or more '#' followed by a
                 # space) and '\s*-\s' (0 or more spaces, a dash then a space)
(?:[^\n]*) # non-capturing group matching the content of the line (literally anything
           # but newline, 0 or more times) because there is something between the
           # beginning I want to ignore and the ending I want to replace (hence group),
           # and I do not want this to be replaced (hence non-capturing).
\n         # the thing I'm matching on, and replacing
/          # separator to announce the replacement for the match
<br>\n     # replacement
/g         # g tag because I want to replace all matching occurences
'          #'
           # end of the command string

 ~/Documents/test/foo # my input/source
```

I've tried using `grep -o` that has a lighter syntax to show the matches (and try to correct my regex) but the '!' in the negative lookback keeps screwing things up and the -F tag doesn't seem to fix it.

Any help is appreciated, and as long as you can provide an example capable of ignoring either
"`# Title\n`" or "  `- list item\n`" in replacing line ends, I'll figure out how to expand it.

#### PS

1. Yes I know that leaving '<br>' on the last line of a paragraph will look bad but I'll fix that later, let's not make regexes insanely long in this small example.
2. While it's true that my example is done in the command line, this is for use in a bash script (hence the tag), so answers should be compatible with bash or provide an explanation why they're not (I'm not extremely familiar with the differences but I read in here that some standarts aren't shared)
3. My environment is Pop!_OS 21.10 (but that shouldn't matter, does it ?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: soooo, why not just like https://markdowntohtml.com/ or https://linuxhint.com/convert-markdown-files-linux/ ? In other words - is this XY problem?

Comment: Why not simply `sed '/^[[:blank:]]*[[:alnum:]]/s/$/<br>/' file` ?

Comment: I want to use a custom css style sheet in my html (linked at the beginning) so I'm writing a local script to wrap around the original perl (https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) markdown to html convertor, since :

 - it doesn't have the same illness as github's viewer that makes it unable to have multiple separated ordered list at the same level

 - the other solutions don't provide an option for a dynamic (argument) css sheet

Comment: @M.NejatAydin : Your solution seems to work nicely, but I'm unable to understand everything, care to expand on that or make it an answer ?

Comment: @Esti If the line begins with an alphanumeric character (optionally preceded by blanks), it appends `<br>` to the line. That's all.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Your usage of $ had me confused. "/match/s/$/append" wasn't something I knew. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp is using PCRE constructs (e.g. lookbacks) but sed doesn't support PCREs, just the POSIX regexp standards of BREs by default and EREs if called with `-E` in GNU or BSD sed.

I'd use awk for this for simplicity and portability. The following will work using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '{print $0 (/^[[:space:]]*([-#]|$)/ ? "" : "<br>")}' file
# Title

paragraph,<br>
with text over multiple lines<br>

- list item
- other list item
 - sublist item
 - sublist item 2
```

---

Original answer:
$ sed 's/^[^-#].*/&
/' file
# Title

```
paragraph,<br>
with text over multiple lines<br>

- list item
- other list item
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide a more truly representative example that includes cases where the above doesn't work.

Comment: Your solution doens't satisfy the requirement [ignoring either "# Title\n" or "  - list item\n" in replacing line ends] since it only works for lines starting with a naked dash.

I do appreciate that you pointed out that using ^for line start and removing the 'g' tag works too, though.

Also I edited the example to include sublists that I described but did not include earlier

Comment: Just saw the edit, thanks for clarifying why my regex would fail.

Comment: @Esti - it's important when asking a question to not just state requirements within your text, but also make sure your example covers them so that when we copy/paste it to test with we get an immediate, clear pass/fail result. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to provide extensive examples if I have to ask a question here. I was hesitant wether or not to provide a very big example file because it would bloat the question but I see that going with a smaller example was a bad choice because it was incomplete.

If I understand correctly, your edited response tries to match a line that's either whitespace only (including empty) or whitespace and one '-' or '#' and only add '\<br>' at the end if it fails to match ?

In any case, your response now covers the full extent of my question, so I'll accept it.

Comment: A "very big" example would be the wrong thing to do too. You're supposed to come up with a [mcve], i.e. a **minimal** example that covers your requirements, so you have to put some effort into really thinking about that. The ERE (regexp) in my code is matching a line that's empty, only white space, or white space followed by `-` or `#` and the ternary is only adding `<br>` if the currently line doesn't match that regexp.